# Get a response from a twilio request

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

I am using `twilio` to send sms to mobile, when i run the script it sends an SMS like it should to my mobile but the problem is i don't know the status of the sent SMS, how do i get that?

What i tried so far is below

```
   <?php
     require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
     use Twilio\Rest\Client;

     // Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
     $account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
     $auth_token = 'your_auth_token';
     // In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
     // $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]

     // A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
     $twilio_number = "+0987654321";

     $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
     $client->messages->create(
     // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
     '+1234567890',
      array(
       'from' => $twilio_number,
       'body' => 'I sent this message in under 10 minutes!'
      )
    );
```

Comment: Please do some proper research before posting a question. I found this after about 10 seconds: https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-confirm-delivery-in-php#what-is-a-webhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing proper research, and having all kind of issues with the webhook, here is what i settled on

```
$phoneString = $phoneNumber->asNorthAmericanDialingString();
$mi          = $client->messages->create(
// the number you'd like to send the message to
    $phoneString ,
    array (
       // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
       'from' => Config::getCurrentConfig()->smsConfig->fromNumber ,
       // the body of the text message you'd like to send
       'body' => $message , 
        'ProvideFeedback' => "true"
    )
);

$msg    = $mi->fetch();
$sid    = $msg->sid;
$status = $msg->status;
if ($status == 'sent' || $status == 'delivered') { // f'ing twilio, random status
    self::getClassLogger()->debug("Sent text message[$sid], status is [$status]");
    return new  TextMessageStatus($sid , $status);
} else {
    // do whatever is appropriate for your case
}
```

Comment: The `ProvideFeedback` parameter is used for the [Message Feedback API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message-feedback). Notably, that is for feedback to Twilio that your message arrived, which can be implied if your user acted upon receiving a message (particularly for phone verification or two factor authentication use cases). What issues did you have with the webhook as that is the best way to get status updates? Also, the status `sent` means Twilio sent it to the network, `delivered` means the network reported it arrived at the device.

Comment: webhook : oh well, how to get this in my dev stack , behind firewalls, with no specific address, while i am developing this ?  As for the random status, from a 'user' perspective of the twilio stack, i should only get one. Also, the call should synchronous in my opinion, and the only one that matters, really, is 'delivered', according to the semantics you gave here (again imnsho).

Comment: For the Webhook I recommend a tool like https://ngrok.com to tunnel through to your local server. The call is not synchronous because message sending is done via a queue. And the statuses are based on the level of information we can get from carriers who don’t always send us delivery receipts, so we tell you as much as we can. “Sent” just means we’ve sent it, “delivered” means the carrier tells us its delivered, so they are different statuses and we believe the granularity is useful.

Comment: @philnash hmm, thanks for the plug, seemingly far better than what i had tried (would work form n-devs).  I want a 'fire and forget' sync, single status from Twilio, with possibility of additional CarrierStatus when you have it. But my workaround is ok for now, will have to judge when we crash the 100K users barrier.  Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Let me know if there’s anything else I can help with. 